# Issues with php_oci8 in IIS server

Tags: php, oci8

We have a php application located in one of our IIS servers, the application normally works with no issue using an oracle connection through oci8. The issue is: it suddenly stopped working.

I automatically started investigating as to why, the application shows the typical error that is found when an oci8 driver is not located:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in E:\serverpath_bla_bla\something.php on line 7
```

At this point I decided to check the php.ini configuration file to make sure that the correct extension is added:

```
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
```

Everything seems to be find on this end, I verified that the oci8 dlls are located inside of the \ext directory and they are. We are using PHP Version 5.3.8
so I thought that maybe by changing the dll to another version such as `php_oci8.dll` would have done it(it is also inside of the ext folder) but it still will not work.

Upon calling `php -m` and/or `php --ini` through the command prompt I see a lot of messages popping up one by one specifying different dlls that are not loaded, which I do not understand since they all are inside of the \ext folder.

The message for the oci8 dll is the most strange:

```
PHP: Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' - the specified procedure could not be found
```

But I can see that the php_oci8_11g.dll is indeed inside of the \ext folder.

What could be missing? Is there something that I am overlooking? Why would the application stop working out of the sudden?

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Why are there two backslashes after `C:\\`? Perhps fixing that will help?

Comment: @Vilx- sorry, that was me being finger happy when i was typing it. I removed the trailing slash from my error message. That is sadly not the issue.

Comment: Update: Still not working for whatever reason. Thought it might be a permissions issue but it is not. It is just not detecting the oci8 dll for some strange reason

Comment: It's also possible that it finds it, but cannot _load_ it, because the DLL initialization fails. In fact, the message kinda hints at that too - `the specified procedure could not be found`. It's not that the _file_ couldn't be found, it's a _procedure_ that couldn't be found. Btw - just a thought - perhaps this is a 64/32-bit issue? Like a 32-bit DLL with a 64-bit PHP executable?

Comment: Also - the PHP OCI DLLs just call into Oracle's OCI DLLs, which, if memory fails me not, reside in `C:\Oracle` or something like that. Perhaps something happened to those recently? Maybe it's a `PATH` issue and PHP's DLLs cannot find Oracle's DLLs?

Comment: @Vilx- thought of that as well. The php version for this server is 32bit and I made that the dlls are the 32 bit as well. The folder with the dlls is in the path. I have literally no clue as to why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have the correct VS redistributable?  Does command line PHP successfully run an OCI8 app? Maybe try a dependency walker to check libraries are installed OK?